# Color "areas of interest" on Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google has just changed the maps colors scheme and it has messed up the custom colors on a site I'm working on. This is the news from their blog:

[Discover the action around you with the updated Google Maps](https://maps.googleblog.com/2016/07/discover-action-around-you-with-updated.html)

Now, not much technical info there. Has anyone already found out where to change that light brown/orange-ish color for "areas of interest"?

From testing [here](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) (and this link is on their dev site), the only thing that does anything to it is `all`, and the more specific you can go is with `Feature type:  all Element type:   geometry.fill`

Comment: Possibly related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 10189: Bug: Strange new map style being displayed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To really 'hide' the areas of interest: first set a color on `all` geometries, and than override that setting by specifying the colors for water, parks, roads et cetera.

Code sample:

```
var myStyle = [
    {featureType: "all", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{color: "#CCCCCC"}]},
    {featureType: "water", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{hue: "#99CCFF"}, {lightness: 30}, {saturation: 50}]},
    {featureType: "road", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{color: "#eeeeee"},{lightness: 30},{visibility: "simplified"}]},
    {featureType: "landscape.natural", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{color: "#c4d7cd"}]},
    {featureType: "poi.park", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{color: "#b4d9c6"}]},
];
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a leap of faith and set modifiers for `"featureType":"areaOfInterest"` and surprisingly it worked!! You can use `areaOfInterest` as the feature type to target styles for it as you would any other feature type.

I set this style and got the following result:

```
{
  "featureType":"areaOfInterest",
  "stylers":[
    {"saturation" : -100},
    {"lightness"  : 25},
    {"visibility" : "simplified"}
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind that this style is for the gmaps4rails gem plugin and the syntax may differ for your application.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for me as well. Although your stylers did not do well on my map, so I just set a `color:` to it on `geometry.fill` :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you! I hope they include this in the official API documentation soon.

Comment: I get the same effect when I use `"featureType":"blaDiBla"`. So there probably is no special feature type for areas of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I took RSmithlal code and slightly amended it to target only the overlay color that covers areas of interest. This way I could keep the label colours unchanged:

```
{
  featureType:'areaOfInterest',
  elementType: 'geometry',
  stylers:[
    {saturation : -100}
  ]
}
```