# what are these pink areas on google maps

Tags: google-maps

I just noticed these pink areas in Chicago's map on google and was wondering what they mean. I checked on several websites and they say the pink areas stand for hospitals. But hospitals cannot be these big across multiple blocks of Chicago downtown. Can anybody help me understand what it indicate?

[image]

Comment: In my contry the pink area are also for city  central or important areas, public building .. school,  .. and so on

Comment: Those are "areas of interest". Duplicate of [Color “areas of interest” on Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599809/color-areas-of-interest-on-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this for Hannover and Hameln (Germany). We have same colour here and from my local knowledge I' think it's for areas of interest (e.g. shopping areas). These are areas where you can spend a lot of money for different things. Think about locations for sponsored links too. It fits the business model of Google.

The snaps (German view of a nice town - it's the Pied Piper of Hamelin) show a pedestrian zone with many shops. Please match the maps.

[image: Google Maps Hamelin Zoom-1]

and zoomIn:

[image: Google Maps Hamelin Zoom-2]

Answer (score 0):

These are boundaries of cities and sub-localities that are displayed when you search for a specific location.

More:
[highlight-areas-in-google-maps](https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/01/highlight-areas-in-google-maps.html#gsc.tab=0)

> When you search for a city or a county or a ZIP Code, Google Maps now highlights the boundaries of what you searched for. If you are zoomed out, the whole area is shaded pink. If you zoom in a bit, it has just a big pink border with grey shading. Zoom in even more and it's a dashed boundary with grey shading.

Credits to:
Rodney G, who commented on "Highlight Areas in Google Maps"